# How to keep header intact of video files while encryption so that I can play the encrypted file in its encrypted form

Tags: java, python, encryption, cryptography

I have written a program to encrypt video files, however I can not open it after encryption. I want the output of the encryption to be able to play the file with encrypted bytes (i.e. Should be able to play the file in its encrypted form) like we do for.png file by keeping their header intact. [Desired output reference](https://www.researchgate.net/figure/Encryption-of-video-file_fig3_283954207)

Comment: You don't need to just make sure that the header is kept intact; you need to make sure that the entire file format stays intact and that the values of the full frames and intermediate frames are within acceptable bounds as well. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

what you intend to do might be a little bit more complicated than what you imagine ...

in order to appear to video tools as a valid file, that can actually be played, you have to understand the corresponding file formats.

with image file-formats like bitmap or png, the header is an actual header, in other words a specific structure, usually at the start of the file, that describes what follows ...

with video formats it's the same but ... isn't...

there are different container formats, and what you need to preserve and what you can encrypt might differ from one to another...

for example mpg (the format you will find on DVDs) can contain numerous streams, which can (afaik) be distributed over multiple files, with each file containing various headers at different locations (a table of contents, headers for each video and audio stream, etc ...)

for those formats you will actually have to decode the headers and calculate the positions (and lengths) of other headers...

so ... even just finding the headers is a piece of work ... which needs to be done once per supported file format, and there are a few... https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Video_file_format

ok, and then we leave the headers, scramble the rest and we have playable encrypted videos, right?

... sadly ... nope...

next up: video and audio encoding/compression

you will actually have to understand how frames and audiosamples are compressed and encoded ... because the software that will decompress and render the images and audio, actually needs valid streams, depending on encoding, this includes checksums and error correction codes ...

but wait ... can't we just, let's say ... re-encode everything into some easy format without most of this crap, and then have something simple like skip the first X bytes and after that encode?

sure thing, but please remember that the original encoding was there for a reason ... maybe the video was intended to be played on certain devices that expect certain encodings -> the video would not be playable there

ok, but can't we re-encode again, just like we did before?

sure thing... but there will most likely be that slight problem with the filesize...

video encodings usually employ some sort of compression ... like using the property of a video that from one frame to another usually not all pixels change ... if we just encode every few frames and the deltas in between, we can store the same video on way less storage space ... or we could employ standard compressions like zip ... yeah... right... not with encrypted data ... you will have a very hard time to compress encrypted data, or save space with the delta approach ... read up on entropy and how compression works for this one ...

oh and one more thing about reencoding after encryption: if you ever want to decrypt, you better make sure that the new encoding can be reversed without any loss of information... not all codecs are lossless

so... why does it have to be playable? is it worth the effort?